# How to test functions using window.navigator.msSaveBlob?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have to write a unit test in angular for window.navigator.msSaveBlob.
how we can write unit test that having 100 branch coverage?

```
msSaveOrOpenBlob() {
    if (window && window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob)
      return true;
    return false
  }

  msSaveBlob(request: Blob, fileName: string) {
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(request, fileName);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests will run in chromium, therefore the msSaveBlob or msSaveOrOpenBlob function will not be defined as they are only available in IE.

For testing purposes you may set them in the individual test on the navigator object itself. E.g.

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = () => true;
window.navigator.msSaveBlob = () => true;
```

Dont forget to unset it after your test was completet so no unwished side effects will occure.

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = undefined;
window.navigator.msSaveBlob = undefined;
```